# Program started from PyCharm not looking like in Kivy-Examples

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I build tree of widgets in kivy-examples and all looking fine. But after i copy a code into pycharm i got something else. What i did bad? I have no idea how to fix it and what could be a reason of this...

```
<MyGrid>
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: 5
    spacing: 5
    BoxLayout:
        text: "Button 1"
        size_hint: 1, .08
        Button:
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, .3
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            GridLayout:
                cols: 2
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
            GridLayout:
                cols: 2
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                Button:
                GridLayout:
                    cols: 2
                    Button:
                    Button:
                    Button:
                    Button:
                BoxLayout:
                    Button:
                    Button:
                    Button:
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, .5
        Button:
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, .12
        Button:
```

[how it look in kivy-examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT74F.jpg)
[and in pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQPIG.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pycharm version the root widget is probably not a layout, so the top level BoxLayout has the default size of (100, 100). Presumably this is the MyGrid from your rule. Make MyGrid inherit from BoxLayout.